# Enable communication site at the root of a tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, modern-experience, communication-site

Iam trying to enable Communication Site on the root site level, but without any luck...

Step 1 was to follow [jimyHang](https://hangconsult.com/2017/06/29/change-sharepoint-online-root-site-collection-to-use-the-new-communication-site-template/) blog, but this approach is not supported anymore, it is not posible anymore...

step 2 was to Enable CommSite by powershell as explained in Demo on ignite and this [blog](https://eschrader.com/2017/11/30/sharepoint-online-enable-new-modern-experience-on-root-site-collection/). Enabling with powershell is not working and iam getting error:`Enable-CommSite : The term 'Enable-CommSite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spell
ing of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

I tried to install all powershell modules available for SPO but still not working:

```
Enable-CommSite -url https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com $username name@yourtenant.com $password puppies123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this command is not shipped yet, you have to wait for it.

As per the below blog, they are roling it out gradually to all tenants. Delivery to you tenants depend upon your release settings.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Build-your-modern-intranet-with-SharePoint-in-Office-365/ba-p/255453